# @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) vs @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test

I was using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` for my junit test with mockito. But now i am working with spring boot app and trying to use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` . Does using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` has any advantages over using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`? Can i still use feature like `@Injectmock`, `@Mock`, `@Spy` with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `SpringRunner` provides support for loading a Spring `ApplicationContext` and having beans `@Autowired` into your test instance. *It actually does a whole lot more than that (covered in the Spring Reference Manual), but that's the basic idea.*

Whereas, the `MockitoJUnitRunner` provides support for creating mocks and spies with Mockito.

However, with JUnit 4, you can only use one `Runner` at a time.

Thus, if you want to use support from Spring and Mockito simultaneously, you can only pick *one* of those runners.

But you're in luck since both Spring and Mockito provide *rules* in addition to *runners*.

For example, you can use the Spring runner with the Mockito rule as follows.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTests {

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Mock
    MyService myService;

    // ...
}
```

Though, typically, if you're using Spring Boot and need to mock a *bean* from the Spring `ApplicationContext` you would then use Spring Boot's `@MockBean` support instead of simply `@Mock`.

Comment: How to replace @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) with a Rule like you did for MockitoJUnit ?

Comment: Using the `SpringClassRule` and `SpringMethodRule`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules

Comment: One more think :) Can i combine it with PowerMock Rules or run with PowerMock synchroniously :) ?

Comment: I don't use PowerMock, so I unfortunately cannot answer that question.

Comment: For example, when testing Spring-Data interfaces I use `@MockBean` BUT when testing JPA query implementation classes I use `@Mock`

Answer (score 15):

When `SpringRunner.class` is used, Spring provides corresponding annotations:

- `@MockBean`
- `@SpyBean`

Mocks are injected to objects under tests via `@Autowired` annotation. To enable this functionality tests must be annotated with

- `@SpringBootTest`

or

- `@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)`

---

More details and examples can be found in the official documentation: [Mocking and Spying Beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans)

Comment: mocks cannot be injected with Autowired, you should use MockBean instead

Comment: @voipp mocks can be injected to tested objects using Autowired, but MockBean is used to define mocks to be injected

Answer (score 5):

As per the JavaDoc:

> SpringRunner is an alias for the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.
>   To use this class, simply annotate a JUnit 4 based test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.
>   If you would like to use the Spring `TestContext` Framework with a runner other than this one, use `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule` and `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringMethodRule`.

And the JavaDoc of `TestContext`:

> `TestContext` encapsulates the context in which a test is executed, agnostic of the actual testing framework in use.

That of method `getApplicationContext()`:

> Get the application context for this test context, possibly cached.
>   Implementations of this method are responsible for loading the application context if the corresponding context has not already been loaded, potentially caching the context as well.

So, SpringRunner does load the context and is responsible for maintaining it. For example, if you want to persist data into an embedded database, like H2 in-memory database, you have to use `SpringRunner.class`; and, to clean the tables to get rid of the records you inserted after every test, you annotate the test with `@DirtiesContext` to tell Spring to clean it.

But, this is already an integration or component test. If your test is pure unit test, you don't have to load DB, or you just want to verify some method of a dependency is called, `MockitoJUnit4Runner` suffices. You just use `@Mock` as you like and `Mockito.verify(...)` and the test will pass. And it is a lot quicker.

Test should be fast. As fast as possible. So whenever possible, use `MockitoJUnit4Runner` to speed it up.

Comment: `SpringRunner` does not load any context it just enable spring boot features like `@Autowire`, `@MockBean`, etc.. during junit testing. If you want to load the context you'd rather use `@SpringBootTest`

Answer (score 1):

## Scenario  2019 November : spring-boot : 2.1.1.RELEASE

- You have a spring boot api rest
- You need to test a service called **MySuperSpringService**
- But, inside MySuperSpringService, are required two more autowires. One to perform a sql select (**MyJpaRepository**) and another to call an external api rest (**MyExternalApiRest**)

```
@Service
public class MySuperSpringService {

  @Autowired
  private MyRepository innerComponent1;

  @Autowired
  private MyExternalApiRest innerComponent2;

  public SomeResponse doSomething(){}
}
```

## How test MySuperSpringService mocking database and external api rest ?

So, in order to test this service **MySuperSpringService** which needs another spring beans: MyJpaRepository and MyExternalApiRest, you need to mock them using **@MockBean** and create the result as you need.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = your.package.Application.class)
public class MySuperSpringServiceTest extends TestCase {

  @Autowired
  private MySuperSpringService serviceToTest;

  @MockBean
  private MyRepository myRepository;

  @MockBean
  private MyExternalApiRest myExternalApiRest;

  @Before
  public void setUp()  {

    Object myRepositoryResult = new Object();
    //populate myRepositoryResult as you need
    when(myRepository.findByClientId("test.apps.googleusercontent.com"))
        .thenReturn(myRepositoryResult);

    Object myExternalApiRestResult = new Object();
    //populate myExternalApiRestResult as you need
    when(myExternalApiRest.listUserRoles("john@doe.com")).thenReturn(myExternalApiRestResult);

  }

  @Test
  public void testGenerateTokenByGrantTypeNoDatabaseNoGoogleNoSecurityV1(){
    SomeResponse response = serviceToTest.doSomething();
    //put your asserts here
  }

}
```

Comment: couple of questions ... is `@SpringBootTest` required and do we need `@MockBean` ? Can this be done simply using `@Mock` ?

Comment: @ SpringBootTest is super required for test!! @ Mock is for simple java classes. If the target class is an spring component with several @ Autowired dentro, @ MockBean is your only option!

Comment: @JRichardsz I don't think so. You can mock the dependencies of the spring component.

Answer (score 0):

you can absolutely use SpringRunner for both unit tests and integration tests.
[SpringRunner Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)